# Javascript/Typescript: How do I detect valid contacts and phone numbers in Android app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, phone-number

In my Android app, I would like to display list of contacts and indicate if they are in the network of my app or not.
However, **I do not want to include all the unwanted contacts (i.e. ex: toll-free numbers, numbers for checking data balance etc..)** 
I would like to display only valid 'contacts'. If possible, I would like to display only smart phone users. 
How do I go about this ?

I am currently filtering out these unwanted contacts using few rules like:
1) If a number starts with 1-800..
2) If the formatted number is not 10-digits

Q1. Is there a simpler standard way to do this ?
Q2. Is there a good set of rules for implementing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a [**Regular Expression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

If you are new to RegEx I'd recommend reading up on them as they are *vital* for most web apps.

If you are pushed for time there is a huge library of expressions [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone+number&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Although I highly recommend learning how to write RegEx.

Some examples:

---

`/[0-9]+`

> Will match **any character in the range 0-9** , there must be at least 1 character.

```
23823 - matched
9382 - matched
2 - matched
foo - not matched
```

---

`/\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b`

> This is a very simple North American Phone Number matcher

```
0123456789 - matched
555.123.4567 - matched
```

As you can see there is a lot of room for complexity with RegEx - this is a very basic RegEx and it does not account for all possible edge cases.